# Notation for Higher Antiderivatives?

Tags: integration

Higher derivative are blessed with many notations.

For example $$ f',f'',...$$ or $$ \frac {dy}{dx}, \frac {d^2 y}{dx^2},...$$
I have not seen any notations for higher anti-derivatives.

For example, the higher anti-derivatives of  $$f(x)=2x+5$$ are $$x^2+5x+c_1, \frac {x^3}{3} +\frac {5}{2}  x^2 + c_1x +c_2,.....$$

Are there notations for higher anti-derivatives?

Comment: I find usually if this is coming up, the boundary conditions are somehow built into the problem, so notations like $\int_0^x \int_0^{x'} f(x'') dx'' dx'$ become suitable.

Comment: @Ian he said antiderivatives not integrals.

Comment: Interesting question. For the first few antiderivatives we just repeat the $\int$ symbol. In fact, latex allows us to write conveniently up to four of them using the \iiiint command, like so: $\iiiint$. At a certain point, of course, this becomes impractical. You could write it this way: $\underbrace{\int\int\cdots\int}_{n\text{ times}}$. But I wonder if there is something more compact.

Comment: @BenW Your last example becomes prettier if you still use the multiple integrals command: $\iint\cdots\int$ versus $\int\int\cdots\int$.

Comment: You may like one of the conventions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_integrals

Comment: @BenW That double integral furnishes a particular second antiderivative of $f$ (assuming $0$ is in its domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Lagrange's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange's_notation_for_antidifferentiation) as detailed in the link, $$\underbrace{\iint\cdots\int}_{n\text{ times}}=f^{(-n)}(x)$$ Using [Newton's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton's_notation_for_integration) as detailed in the link, $$\underbrace{\iint\cdots\int}_{n\text{ times}}=\overset{n}{\overset{'}{y}}$$ although it "did not become widespread because of printing difficulties."